# addClass() to direct child only (and not nested elements)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following markup:

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 2</a>
  
  <ul class="hamburgerMenu__menu--levelTwo">
    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do, via JQuery, is to add the class `remove` to the `a` tags that are outside the `ul`. So I'm trying to achieve the following markup:

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item remove">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item remove">Link 2</a>
  
  <ul class="hamburgerMenu__menu--levelTwo">
    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

To achieve the above, I have tried the following:

`$('.menu').children("a").addClass("remove");`

However, the above adds `remove` to all the anchor tags, evevn the one's in the `ul`.

How can I only add `remove` to the `a` tags outside of the `ul`

Comment: use > for immediates

Comment: It works. can you create an evidence?

Answer (score 3):

Use > symbol to target immediate children and you don't need jquery for that, plain js is enough.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.menu > a').forEach(link => link.classList.add("remove"))
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item remove">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item remove">Link 2</a>

  <ul class="hamburgerMenu__menu--levelTwo">
    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```